# Iterar um formulário com JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um formulário com alguns itens, sendo que algumas células contem os dados de código do banco e código de conta a receber.

Numa mesma célula possuo 2 `inputs` distintos, um `checkbox` e um `hidden`. Eu preciso iterar e pegar os valores de todos os `checkboxes` que estiverem marcados, incluindo o valor do campo `hidden` desta célula. Este campo é o código do banco para gerar o boleto.

Ou seja pode ter mais de uma conta a receber de um mesmo banco.
Preciso depois de iterar enviar cada conta a receber para o seu devido boleto.

Segue abaixo um trecho do código:

```
<form id="frmGrid">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkboleto" value="119" checked />
            <input type="hidden" name="hdn_banco" value="001" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkboleto" value="120" />
            <input type="hidden" name="hdn_banco" value="001" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkboleto" value="130" checked/>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdn_banco" value="100" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkboleto" value="140" checked/>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdn_banco" value="100" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro ires buscar primeiro os elementos que estão "checados" com

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
```

depois podes usar essa coleção/array e mapear para teres outro conteúdo lá dentro. Assim iterando podes retornar um objeto com informação desse checkbox e também do próximo elemento `hidden` que é seu sibing e pode ser obtido atravéz do [método `.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

Uma função com isto seria:

```
var checked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
   var hidden = $(this).next()[0];
    return {
        checkbox: {name: this.name, value: this.value},
        hidden: {name: hidden.name, value: hidden.value}
    }
}).get();
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3me57xrh/

e estaria pronto para mandar para o servidor com AJAX como JSON. Algo assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "pagina.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(checked),
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data) {
         alert('dados enviados!';
    }
});
```

Comment: Muito bom o seu exemplo. Além de me ajudar bastante me fez ir à api do Jquery estudar o que usou no exemplo de resolução que me deste. Se não for abusar demais gostaria que me disesse como gerar mais de um boleto para um banco.

Comment: @Fininhors o que é "boleto"? em Portugal não usamos esse nome.

Comment: Boleto bancário, é um documento que possui um valor a ser pago em um banco(local fisico) ou pelo internet banking.

Comment: @Fininhors queres dizer que queres gerar mais uma `<form>` e enviar para o servidor?

Comment: quero dizer que preciso pegar os pares de codigos hidden.value e this.value e gera um documento. Para cada hidden.value pega-se os referidos valores do chekbox e gera o seu documento. Entendeu??

Comment: @Fininhors a variável `checked` no meu exemplo tem isso. Queres gerar isso no PHP ou JavaScript? para a base de dados ou para o cliente... não entendi bem. Se calhar é melhor fazer outra pergunta e assim tens mais espaço para explicar

Comment: @Sergio Se eu entendi bem, ele basicamente quer fazer um `ajax` pra cada `checkbox`.

Answer (score 2):

É só uma questão de usar seletores do jQuery para achar os elementos. Vou explicá-los:

1. **`td:has(input[type='checkbox'])`:** obter todos os `td` que possuem um `input` cujo `type='checkbox'`
2. de posse dos `td`s, para cada um deles, obter o input `checkbox` e o input `text`, respectivamente:

   - **`input[type='checkbox']`**
   - **`input[type='text']`**

```js
var tds = $("td:has(input[type='checkbox'])");

var msg = "";

$.each(tds, function(i, v) {
  var checkbox = $("input[type='checkbox']", this).val();
  var hidden = $("input[type='hidden']", this).val();
  var data = JSON.stringify({
    checkbox: checkbox,
    hidden: hidden
  });
  msg += data + "\n";
});

alert(msg);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmGrid">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkboleto" value="119" checked />
        <input type="hidden" name="hdn_banco" value="001" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkboleto" value="120" />
        <input type="hidden" name="hdn_banco" value="001" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkboleto" value="130" checked/>
        <input type="hidden" name="hdn_banco" value="100" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkboleto" value="140" checked/>
        <input type="hidden" name="hdn_banco" value="100" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```